# @BeforeMethod/@AfterMethod(onlyForGroups) methods did not execute, if a test method belonging to this group is executed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running a test suite with the test methods belonging to a certain groups.

**Below is the Selenium code:**

```
public class BaseClass
{

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P1"})
    public void bmeth1()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method1 called");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P2"})
    public void bmeth2()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method2 called");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P3"})
    public void bmeth3()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method3 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P1"})
    public void ameth1()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method1 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P2"})
    public void ameth2()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method2 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P3"})
    public void ameth3()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method3 called");
    }

}

public class TC_003 extends BaseClass
{

    @Test(groups = {"P1"})
    public void tCase6()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside testcase 6");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"P2"})
    public void tCase7()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside testcase 7");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"P3"})
    public void tCase8()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside testcase 8");
    }

}
```

**Below is the testng.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="10">
<test name="Test1">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name=".*"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="testing.TC_003"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Inside testcase 6
Inside testcase 7
Inside testcase 8
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Before Method1 called
Inside testcase 6
After Method1 called
Before Method2 called
Inside testcase 7
After Method2 called
Before Method3 called
Inside testcase 8
After Method3 called
```

The test methods are executed, but the @BeforeMethod/@AfterMethod did not execute. This issue occurs only if we include certain groups in testng.xml file. But if we exclude certain groups or do not use groups tag in testng.xml file, then they are executed.

As suggested [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/549#issuecomment-565603414), the current workaround is to use alwaysRun=true flag along with onlyForGroups flag. But if we apply this workaround, and if there is any SkipException in the preceding/parent config methods, then it is forced to execute the @BeforeMethod/@AfterMethod methods, even when the test method is going to be skipped. There is a similar issue logged [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1622), when the preceding/parent config methods has failed.

Comment: your code works as it is are ou using 7.3.0 lates testng ?

Comment: I am using 7.3.0 latest testng...

Comment: Your code works in my system

Comment: It prints out as expected

Comment: Which testng version are you using?

Comment: Did you try to include groups in testng.xml file?

Comment: Yes same testing version and your text xml

Comment: I am using Maven pom.xml to manage dependencies..

Comment: Same with me , I executed the test both by surefire and using testng xml , both cases it works as expected

Comment: May be try rebuilding the project

Comment: I tried rebuild, but got the same result.

Comment: I am using selenium-java 4.0.0-alpha-7 version.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan - Can you please help on this issue?

Comment: i am using the same version and approaches still things as expected , you are sure there is no other other @Before or after method you forgot to uncomment or something ?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: I have found a workaround for this issue which I had raised in stackoverflow. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66310524/11014052).

Comment: I used regex it works well

Comment: I don't understand why my code is not running? Do you have your code on Github?

Comment: give me few mins i will push it to git hub

Comment: https://github.com/praveendvd/stack this is the github link

Comment: I download our project and then executed it on my machine. I got the same output as my code.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jHbHZdC

Comment: see the output image , please add your  console output screenshot

Comment: I have uploaded the Testng console output [here](https://ibb.co/y6vwVCv)

Comment: Add screenshot , see the image I added

Comment: I use java 1.8..is it because of this ?

Comment: Can you please try using java 1.8?

Comment: in your code its purely testng why will selenium version affect it , testng and selenium are separate projects

Comment: in the pom you only need tetng as dependency nothing else

Comment: Then why your code is giving different outputs? Any reason?

Comment: it works as expected for me , delete everything creat a new folder and clone that repo do mvn install and mvn test

Comment: I deleted everything and then cloned your repo in my workspace. Now when I do `mvn clean`, I am getting `Build Failure [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\stack). Please verify yo
u invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: did you do mvn clean from stack folder ?

Comment: it has the POM.xml in it

Comment: It created a folder stack and inside there is a folder named selenium and .git and .gitignore. Now inside the selenium folder there is pom.xml file.

Comment: ya do it in the folder that has pom file

Comment: I am getting build failure after doing mvn test-compile. `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
8.0:compile (default-compile) on project Selenium_basic: Fatal error compiling:
invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]`

Comment: you just have to do mvn clean , mvn install , not test compile

Comment: are you using testng or mvn to execute the file ?

Comment: now i understood what you were trying , mvn test doesn't invoke that but testng does

Comment: I am getting the same error for mvn install.

Comment: Ok...I got the reason why I am getting this error. It is because in my system I have java 1.8 and in your system you have version 11 and you have mentioned this version in your pom.xml file under maven-compiler-plugin..let me comment this configuration and then run

Comment: Now i am getting Tests are skipped because you have mentioned <skipTests>true</skipTests> in maven surefire plugin. let me comment this statement as well..

Comment: Still i got the same output: Inside testcase 6
Inside testcase 7
Inside testcase 8

Comment: yes i understood what you meant i am looking into it

Comment: just replace onlyforgroups with groups

Comment: But if we replace onlyforgroups with groups, then for every test method, it executes all the BeforeMethods regardless of the groups. Check [here](https://ibb.co/dfz4d76).

Comment: it doesn't if you sepcify groups in in testng.xml try changing it and running

Comment: i have added information on how to mix the two also

Comment: I have already included the groups. Check my testng.xml file (https://ibb.co/j5hH8Dg)

Comment: Did you try replacing onlyforgroups with groups? I observed that it executes all the BeforeMethods/AfterMethods regardless of the groups for every test method, even after including the groups in testng xml file

Comment: could you try the updated code just clone the repo again and run mvn clean,. mvn install , mvn test in stack\selenium

Comment: I tried your updated code, and it gives me the expected result, but i think it is redundant to include both groups and onlyForGroups tag

Comment: Testng doc mentions that `onlyForGroups  Only for @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod. If specified, then this setup/teardown method will only be invoked if the corresponding test method belongs to one of the listed groups.`

Comment: Please read the updated answer groups defines the group a method belongs to , so if you specify that in testng.xml then only those groups get executed

Comment: so if your before and after is in that group or doesn't has alwaysrun enabled , it won't get invoked

Comment: Also, another question is why do we have to use both groups and onlyForGroups flags, only when we include the groups. If we exclude the groups or do not use groups tag, then the onlyForGroups flag is sufficient...

Comment: yes because all the methods get invoked if we don't sepcify that in testng.xml

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if it helped , added more clearer explanation

Comment: Wow. Thanks for such a clear explanation. I also got some more information here as well. https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/549#issuecomment-278903677. I think onlyforgroups flag is meant to create a relation between test/config methods belonging to same group. Whereas groups flag at test/config method level does not create any relation between methods having same group name, it is just to include/invoke all those methods which have same group names as the groups mentioned under include tag in testng.xml file.

Comment: yes thats correct :) groups and always run is just for invoking , only gtoup is to create relation ship

Comment: Once again thanks very much. I would have given your answer thousand upvotes if it was possible. :)

Comment: Thanks for asking this brilliant question , i was running the tests from testng runner in eclipse and it was not using the testng.xml so was behaving as expected thats why i couldn't figure out what you where trying at first. COuld have upvoted 10000 times to the question also

Comment: Looks like the party is over, if you do need more please make a chatroom so the stack cleaning bots don't blow up my flags =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its an interesting observation if you change onlyforgroups to groups then everything works:**

but when there are multiple groups included in your testng.xml then all before and after method in mentioned group get executed before every test method . so  in order to avoid this you have to mix groups and onlygroups together

### Explanation:

If you don't specify group in testng xml then all methods get invoked. but if you mention group then only methods in that particular group get executed.

this is because if you read the definition of groups:

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

> groups    The list of groups this class/method belongs to.

so if you don't mention the group or always run true then the method is not invoked so you won't get the before and after method invoked as they are not in any group

### Work around:

**you can mix the two as :**

```
package driversetup;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;



public class TestBaseClass  {
    

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P1"},groups = {"P1"})
    public void bmeth1()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method1 called");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P2"},groups = {"P2"})
    public void bmeth2()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method2 called");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P3"},groups = {"P3"})
    public void bmeth3()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method3 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P1"},groups = {"P1"})
    public void ameth1()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method1 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P2"},groups = {"P2"})
    public void ameth2()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method2 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P3"},groups = {"P3"})
    public void ameth3()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method3 called");
    }
    

}
```

**or enable always run true**

```
package driversetup;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;



public class TestBaseClass {
    

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P1"},alwaysRun = true)
    public void bmeth1()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method1 called");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P2"},alwaysRun = true)
    public void bmeth2()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method2 called");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P3"},alwaysRun = true)
    public void bmeth3()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method3 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P1"},alwaysRun = true)
    public void ameth1()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method1 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P2"},alwaysRun = true)
    public void ameth2()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method2 called");
    }

    @AfterMethod(onlyForGroups = {"P3"},alwaysRun = true)
    public void ameth3()
    {
        System.out.println("After Method3 called");
    }
    

}
```

**this ensures that the before and after method gets invoked, but get executed only for correct @test methods**